# facet-grid with two different geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a facet_grid with one density (Age) and one marplot (Gender). My try does not give the desired output, basically just an empty plot. Any suggestions?

```
 ggplot() +
  facet_grid(Loc~Group, scales="free_y", space = "free_y") +
  geom_density(data = Age, aes(x=Age)) +
  geom_col(data = Gender,aes(x=Loc ,y=n, fill=gender))
```

Age:

```
> as.data.frame(head(Age))
                    Loc Age Group
1               Breast  57   Age
2                 Lung  60   Age
3                 Skin  66   Age
4                 Lung  69   Age
5                 Lung  54   Age
6               Uterus  48   Age
```

Gender:

```
                  Loc gender  n  Group
1                 Anus female 18 Gender
2                 Anus   male 12 Gender
3                Vulva female 12 Gender
4               Vagina female  2 Gender
5              Stomach female 20 Gender
6              Stomach   male 62 Gender
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Seems like your intention is to make to plots side-by-side, not a facet one. For a facet grid you need a shared axis

Comment: so its not possible to make a facet with two different geom-types?

Comment: Not impossible, but for the most part it would be a rather convoluted way to achieve the same result that can be done much more naturally using 2 separate plots. If you have a good reason why you want one faceted plot, do elaborate so others can understand better.

Comment: Pretty close to impossible.  You cannot have two different axes entirely between facets, although you can have different ranges represented.  If both axes were numeric, you would have to first scale both together in some way, then mess with limts and axis breaks... a mess, but *possible*.  In OP's example, one axis is discrete and one is continuous.  There's really not a good way to split those to my mind.  I highly suggest `patchwork` or `cowplot::plot_grid()` or `ggpubr::ggarrange()` for this kind of combined plot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `patchwork` to create a side-by-side plot with a barplot and density plot like this:

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = Gender, aes(x=Loc ,y=n, fill=gender))

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_density(data = Age, aes(x=Age)) 

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>